# How to uninstall flutter MacOS, Windows and Linux debug build from my laptop like in Android and iOS from smartphone?

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows, flutter-build, flutter-linux, flutter-macos-2.0.0-stable

I have done some searching regarding this but did not find any solution yet thats why i am asking.

Normally when ever we uninstall application from Mobile phone, all data clears and event if we don't want to unistall the application, we have option to clear all data which reset installed application and removed shored information from storage.

I want to clear previously stored data from my MacOS flutter build even not for windows too.

If anyone have an idea then please share this.

Thanks

Flutter application is not available in Applications folder (MacOS)

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your Xcode-caches to remove previous data.

On your Mac go to: About this Mac -
Go to: More Info -
Go to: Storage -
There click on Developer, and in the new window clear Xcode-caches.